# Swing/AWT fillRect loop with PRNG not displaying randomly?

Tags: java, swing, random, graphics

I have an issue I can't figure out. I am trying to display a bunch of boxes randomly around the screen but instead it's like it only displays the boxes in one line. It's like they line up instead of displaying randomly even though the values I log are super random.

Here is an image of how it's currently looking:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mExkj.png)

Here is my `JPanel` extension used to draw the boxes:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CustomComponent extends JPanel {

    private Color[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.DARK_GRAY,Color.GRAY,Color.GREEN, Color.LIGHT_GRAY,Color.MAGENTA,Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW};
    
    double r;
    double maxWidth     = 2000;
    double maxHeight    = 2000;
    double width        = maxWidth;
    double height       = maxHeight;
    
    public CustomComponent() {
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension((int) maxWidth,(int) maxHeight));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) maxWidth,(int) maxHeight));
    }

     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);

         int count = 0;
         while (count < 50) {
             r = Math.random();
             g.setColor(colors[(int)(colors.length * r)]);
             g.fillRect((int) (1000*r), (int) (1000*r), (int) (1000*r), (int) (1000*r));
             count++;
         }
      }
}
```

The `CustomComponent` is used here:

```
public JPanel northComponent() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        CustomComponent j = new CustomComponent();
        panel.add(j);
        return panel;
    }
```

I'm using a layout manager with `BorderLayout` where the panel object is positioned north.

Comment: *"I'm using a layout manager with borderlayout.."* In what container? Note that the *default* layout for a `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`, which might explain the *"boxes in one line"*. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: A painting method is for painting only. You should not change the state of the class in the painting method. Every time the component get repainted you will generate new random rectangles. See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/)

Answer (score 0):

you create **one** random for all **four** attributes of the rectangle:

```
r = Math.random();
g.fillRect(r, r, r, r); //simplified
```

you should create **four** randoms for all **four** parameters:

```
xpos = Math.random();
ypos = Math.random();
width = Math.random();
height = Math.random();
g.fillRect(xpos, ypos, width, height); //simplified
```

i hope this answer is self explaining, if you have issues, please leave a comment - happy coding!